# ruby program in sublime text 2 throws "undefined method" error in saved .rb files

Tags: ruby

This is the Dungeon example from Beginning Ruby:

```
class Dungeon
def add_room(reference, name, description, connections)
    @rooms << Room.new(reference, name, description, connections,)
end

class Player
    attr_accessor :name, :location

    def initialize(player_name)
        @name = player_name
    end
end

def initialize(player_name)
    @player = Player.new(player_name)
    @rooms = []
end
end
my_dungeon = Dungeon.add_room(:largecave, "Large Cave", "a large cavernous cave", {:west => :smallcave})
my_dungeon = Dungeon.add_room(:smallcave, "Small Cave", "a small claustrophobic cave", {:east => :largecave})
```

This code builds without error in Sublim Text 2 until I save it to a file on my HD. Once it's saved to my PC I get this build error from Sublime Text 2

```
C:/Ruby193/bin/stephon.rb:18:in `<main>': undefined method `add_room' for Dungeon:Class (NoMethodError)
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I used the `%PATH%` command in a comm window to add both the directory that this code is in and the Ruby directory. No change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are your classes nested like that? Also, you should extend the Ruby load path using `-I`.

Answer (score 0):

The `add_room` method on your `Dungeon` class is an instance method. That means, you must create a new instance of the class before you can call the method on the instance.

Something like this should work (as long as you define a `Room` class somewhere):

```
my_dungeon = Dungeon.new("Player 1")
my_dungeon.add_room(:largecave, "Large Cave", "a large cavernous cave", {:west => :smallcave})
my_dungeon.add_room(:smallcave, "Small Cave", "a small claustrophobic cave", {:east => :largecave})
```